# Plotting line chart from data group of data separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I want to show one line graph for each group of data from pandas dataframe.

Dataframe:

|  | tag | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 21 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 22 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 20 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 | 21 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | 22 | 14 |

I tried to execute the below:

```
for tag_g in df.groupby('tag'):
        tag_g.plot( 'date' , 'value' )
```

It gives an error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'plot'

Notes:

- Will there be only 2 groups? **No, its dynamic.** *Can have 1 or n number*
- Will there be 3 rows for each group? **No, its dynamic.** *But minimum 3 for sure*

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration is incorrect. Try this:

```
for g, frame in df.groupby("tag"):
    frame.plot("date", "value")
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) for more on iterating through groups.

Comment: ohh, yes. And currently it opens multiple windows for each chart, can there be single window and next previous option two view different charts?

Comment: That's IDE specific. You'll have to read the relevant docs and settings you need.